# Nonconvex Optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-programming, nonconvex

Consider the following optimization problem:

$\text{max}_{p} \quad ||p||^2 \\ 
s.t: x\geq 0\\
p\in D$

where $D$ is a convex set. Is this problem $\mathcal{NP}$-hard?

Comment: You might just as well write this problem as $\max \| p \|^{2}$ subject to $p \in D$.

Comment: Do you mean to say $x\le \|p\|^2$ for *any* $p\in D$, or for *all* $p\in D$? I suppose the former, but it would help to clarify your question.

Comment: The "for all $p \in D$" version of the problem is convex- it amounts to $\min \| p \|$ subject to $p \in D$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Feasibility checking](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/feasibility-checking)

Comment: @Star: This question isn't a duplicate of the feasibility checking question.

Comment: In its current form the variable $x$ seems to have no connection to the optimization problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your original problem statement is vague in that you haven't described how the convex set $D$ would be encoded.

The problem simplifies immediately to

$\max \| p \|^{2}$

subject to

$p \in D$.

We'll show that this problem is NP-Hard by reduction from 0-1 Integer Linear
Programming feasibility.

The 0-1 Integer Linear Programming feasibility problem is a well known NP-Complete problem:  "Given integer matrices $A$ and $b$, is there a 0-1 vector $x$ such that $Ax=b$?"

Consider the change of variables $y_{i}=2x_{i}-1$.  Then our original problem becomes "Is there a vector $y$ with $y_{i}=\pm 1$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$, such
that $\hat{A}y=\hat{b}$?"  It's easy to see that this transformation produces a new instance of size polynomial in the size of the original problem.

Now, suppose that we could solve

$\max \| y \|^{2}$

subject to

$\hat{A}y=\hat{b}$

$ -1 \leq y_{i} \leq 1$, for $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

in polynomial time.  The optimal value is $n$ if and only $y$ has a solution in which all entries are $\pm 1$.  The feasible set for this optimization problem is clearly convex.  A polynomial time algorithm to find the optimal $y$ would give us a polynomial time algorithm for the original 0-1 ILP feasibility problem.

This shows that in general, the problem

$\max \| p \|^{2}$

subject to

$p \in D$

is NP-Hard, even if $D$ is restricted to being convex.

Comment: Aren't you making the assumption here that $D$ is given as the intersection of half-spaces, i.e., as a polytope? What if $D$ is a general but smoothly bounded convex set?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth you've got the logic slightly backwards.  I'm saying that if you can solve the problem for an arbitrary convex set $D$ in polynomial time then you can solve the problem for the particular convex set ${y | \hat{A}y=\hat{b}, -1 \leq y_{i} \leq 1, i=1, 2, \ldots, n}$ in polynomial time, and if you can do that you can solve the 0-1 ILP feasibility problem in polynomial time.

Comment: @ Brian Borchers: What is your assumption on $D$. I think that for the sets $D$ that are empty or can be described as a polynomial number of extreme points, the problem is still tractable. However, it may be intractable in general.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: But there are, of course, sets $D$ for which the problem is very simple to solve. For example if $D$ is described by a very small number of variables, e.g., a ball of known radius and known center. This problem is much simpler to solve than if I gave you either an interior or exterior polyhedral approximation to the ball.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: BrianBorchers is making the type of argument I suggested Star make. Essentially, you argue that an instance of an NP-complete problem can be transformed "easily" into the problem class described by Star. It's true that as you narrow the problem class, it may be possible to construct more efficient means of solving the problem (for instance, knowing that an optimization problem is convex enables the use of polynomial-time algorithms; for a problem that is not known to be convex, it may not be possible to use those algorithms and obtain a solution).

Comment: @Brian: The following optimization problem: max $||p||^2$ s.t: $p\in D$ is convex when $D$ is convex. Now how did you claim that this problem is NP-hard even if $D$ is convex. Should not any convex optimization problem be tractable?

Comment: @Star The problem $\max \| p \|^{2}$ s.t. $p \in D$ where $D$ is convex is not a convex optimization problem, because you're maximizing a convex function over a convex set rather than minimizing a convex function over a convex set.

Answer (score 0):

Show that an $\mathcal{NP}$-complete problem reduces to your problem in polynomial time. A classic example of this for nonconvex optimization is the [reduction from subset sum to nonconvex optimization by Murty and Kabadi](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~murty/np.pdf). For your specific problem, you will have to formulate a similar type of reduction. You might be able to leverage work done on quadratically-constrained quadratic programs.